# Apply a filter to a section in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with multiple sections that link to other crystal reports which feed off the input parameters. I want to apply a filter to one of the report sections to only display a policy count >=5. However I don't want this applied to any of the other reports/sections.

I tried suppressing rows using policy count but it looks messy and then I have a total count in the report footer which does not match after suppressing the data, so filtering the data seems the best option.

I thought using a formula like the below would work via Report Grouping;

```
if ({ReportName}= "Filter Report Name") then ({Policy Count} >=5 )
else if ({ReportName}= "other report") then ({Policy Count} >= 0)
```

However this returns 0 records for the Report I want to filter. The measure I want to filter on is on all the report sections, but i only want it applied to this 1 report/section. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks,

Blowers

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out...I ended up suppressing the section uisng; {Policy Count} >=4
and then checked Suppressed Blank Section.
Thanks
Blowers